# Conditional Fields Changed Answer Problem

Tags: entities

I have three fields on an entityform the third is hidden unless the second one is answered with yes.

The problem I have is that if a user makes three visible by answering "yes" and then answers three but then decided to change question 2 to  "no" field 3 is hidden but the answer is still recorded.

Comment: And why exactly would that be a problem? That way if user switches from yes to no, and few days later from no to yes, he does not need to re-type answer to 3rd question, right? Sounds good to me.

Comment: I've changed the wording, it may make more sense. The problem is if the user changes their mind on question 2 at the time of submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another dependency with **field 3** - **emptied** when **question 2** is **no** should most likely fix your problem